# Bash Script exiting without error while using diff

Tags: bash, diff, exit

I'm fairly new to using bash and was trying to create an autograder script for running some test cases. Currently my bash script seems to be acting strangely; when I have the -e flag set bash will just exit when a diff has a positive size, and when the -e flag is not set the script ignores any differences in the diff files and says that all tests passed.

The script exits immediately after the "write_diff_out=...." command, the next line is not printed. I've only included the diffing portion of the script as everything else runs fine (the files all exist as well).

```
# Validate outputs and print results
echo "> Comparing current build's final memory output with golden memory output...";
for file in `ls test_progs`;
do
    file=$(echo $file | cut -d '.' -f1);
    echo "$file";
    write_diff_out=$(diff ./log/$file.writeback.out ./log/$file.writeback.gold.out > ./diff/$file.writeback.diff);
    echo "Finished write_diff";
    program_diff_out=$(diff -u <(grep -E '@@@' ./log/$file.program.out) <(grep -E '@@@' ./log/$file.program.gold.out) > ./diff/$file.program.diff);
    echo "Finished program diff";

    if [ -z "$write_diff_out" ] && [ -z "$program_diff_out" ]; then
        printf "%20s:\e[0;32mPASSED\e[0m\n" "$file";
    else
        printf "%20s:\e[0;31mFAILED\e[0m\n" "$file";
    fi
done
echo "> Done comparing test outputs.";
```

Feel free to suggest a better way of formatting the diff commands as well, I know there are different methods of writing them.

Comment: Just a tip: [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), do `for file in test_progs/*` instead. Also, you don't need `;` in the end of line (it's used to separate commands in the same line, `like; this`)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `-e flag`. Do you mean `bash -e` or `diff -e`? I also can't understand what you are trying to accomplish with `write_diff_out=$(diff ... ... > diff/$file.writeback.diff)`. You perhaps should test if `diff/$file.writeback.diff` is empty.

Comment: The -e flag is the bash -e I believe (the one you call "set -e" for at the top of the bash script). The write_diff_out variable was meant to contain the contents of the diff, while also writing the diff to the specified file. The method you posted below looks cleaner though so I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Oh, so it makes sense. Here is the help for `-e`: `Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.`. I think that using it is a terrible idea, because it has too many corner cases, its behavior changed with different bash versions and there are some rogue programs that return bogus exit codes (0 should always mean "success" and non-zero should mean "failure"). I have no idea why diff returned non-zero, perhaps it didn't find the specified filenames. You could test for their existence beforehand, with `if [[ -f filename1 && -f filename 2 && .. ]]; then ..`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly know what's your problem, but I have rewritten your script to conform to some best practices. Perhaps it will work better.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Debugging mode: prints every command as executed, remove when uneeded
set -x

# Validate outputs and print results
echo "> Comparing current build's final memory output with golden memory output..."

cd test_progs

for file in *; do
    file="$(echo "$file" | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//')"
    echo "$file"

    # will PASS when both diffs return non-zero

    if ! diff "log/$file.writeback.out" \
              "log/$file.writeback.gold.out" > \
              "diff/$file.writeback.diff" && \
       ! diff -u <(grep -E @@@ "log/$file.program.out") \
                 <(grep -E @@@ "log/$file.program.gold.out") > \
                 "diff/$file.program.diff"; then
        printf '%20s:\e[0;32mPASSED\e[0m\n' "$file"
    else
        printf '%20s:\e[0;31mFAILED\e[0m\n' "$file"
    fi
done

echo "> Done comparing test outputs."
```

It avoids parsing ls, [use quotes where it is due](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting), used [[[](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29) instead of [ (you don't need to quote variables inside of [[), and it tests if the written file is empty instead of storing something at a variable.

If you really wanted to store diff's output in a variable, you would do this:

```
write_diff_out="$(diff "log/$file.writeback.out" "log/$file.writeback.gold.out" | tee "diff/$file.writeback.diff")"
```

Then `$write_diff_out` would contain the same data the `diff/$file.writeback.diff` file has.

**EDIT**: edit my answer a bit, to implement some of the things in the comments.

Comment: You can drop the quotes around filenames if you guarantee that $file will never contain spaces (perhaps because you're creating them yourself and would always be vigilant against awful filenames). But you *can't* drop the quotes around `$(diff...)`, because the output of diff might contain spaces and other separators (see the links I provided). Also, if your filenames have multiple dots, your `cut` might not do what you expect (it will cut after the first dot, so `filey.name.c` will become `filey`)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and put some of this to use later on and let you know how it went. Good point on the file name structure with cut, I'll have to make sure to name them appropriately... just using it to take a file name such as memtest.s and get the filename without the extension. Perhaps just removing the last . would be preferable.

Comment: I almost corrected your cut, maybe this behavior was intended but it felt *wrong*. Here is a correct version with sed: `file="$(echo "$file" | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//')"`

Comment: A few notes:

1. The `for file in test_progs/*` line wound up appending test_progs/ to the front of my file name. Is there a way around this so I don't need to parse ls?

2. Your new version of cut seems to be the same as the old version in that it only returns the part of the file before the '.'. I tried using the filename test.file.hello.s and both versions returned 'test'.

3. Setting the "-e" flag wound up killing my script on a non-zero diff, perhaps this is expected when calling the command directly in a bash script.

Comment: Tried to edit my comment above, but I guess that's not possible after 5 minutes. diff returns 1 when the output files are different and so the script is exiting as a command returned non-zero, just as the -e flag is meant to do. To get around this I just set +e around my diffs.

Comment: @BillB 1. You can do `cd test_progs` and then do `for file in *`, 2. Yep, the cut is identical. See my sed one in the comments, 3. You want to exit when the files are different? Perhaps you should put `|| exit 1` after your diff command then, instead of using `set -e`. But why would you want this? This will mean that neither "PASSED" or "FAILED" will be printed.

Comment: @BillB Also, there are a issue on my answer: the `diff ... > file` always create the file, so the script always prints PASSED (because the files always exist). What you actually wanted to do is to print PASSED when **both the diffs are non-empty**, that is, when both diffs returned non-zero, right?

Comment: Oh no, I didn't want to exit when the file was different. That's why I used "set +e" around my diffs, so that won't happen. Always creating the file is fine and desired, it should just have 0 size (which it seems to). If I use "cd test_progs", I'll also need to modify where the log files go (the log directory should be in the same directory as the test_progs directoy), but that's minor.